# Python 3- POST request to get bearer token

Tags: python-3.x, api, bearer-token

I am trying to get a bearer token without hard coding credentials (userID and password)

import requests

import pprint

userID = input ("Enter your login ID: ")

password = input ("Enter your password: ")

headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}

data = 'client_id=1234&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password&scope=api&username=**{userID}**&password=**{password}**'

response = requests.post('https://api.example.com/connect/token', headers=headers, data=data)

pprint.pprint(response.json())

But even after entering correct userID and password I am getting error:

**{'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Wrong username or password'}**

Answer (score 1):

I guess you forgot to make your data string an [f-string](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-f-strings-tutorial-how-to-use-f-strings-for-string-formatting/)

Your data string should be:

```py
f'client_id=1234&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password&scope=api&username={userID}&password={password}'
```